# React Bootstrap CSS alignment

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using the following div to generate the attached picture. Is there a recommended way to get the the two icons to align?

[image]

```
<div className='my_node'>
        
        <div style = {{display:"flex"}}>
         
         <Button variant="light" style={{margin: '0px'}} onClick={handleShow}><BiEdit className="transparent-layer"  /></Button>
          <div  style={{ paddingTop: '2px',  boxSizing: 'content-box'}} > {data.label} </div>
          <CloseButton style ={{paddingTop: '6px', marginLeft:"auto"}} name ="deleteNode"/>
        </div>
        
      </div>
```

Here are my relevant imports:

```
import { Handle } from 'react-flow-renderer';
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';
import CloseButton from 'react-bootstrap/CloseButton';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
//import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
//import InputGroup from 'react-bootstrap/InputGroup';
import { Form, Button, FormControl, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import {BiEdit}  from 'react-icons/bi';
```

**Edit**
Here's the image post Junaid's suggestion below. The gray square still visible/impacting the text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using flex
add flex to the Button as well

```
     <div style = {{display:"flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"between"}}>
     <Buttonstyle 
         style={{display:"flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"center", margin: '0px'}} 
         variant="light" 
         onClick={handleShow}
     >
         <BiEdit className="transparent-layer"  />
     </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Mostly there. However, if the word is shorter, like "hi", it goes to the left, right next to the edit button.

Comment: answer updated!!

Comment: Ah, perfect, one last question then: If you look closely, you'll see a slight gray outline to the icon on the left from where the Bootstrap button is. When I do "alignItems" the button is then used for the alignment (rather than the Icon) so it looks skewed to the right. Any way how I can "shrink" the button to be as close to the icon as possible?

Comment: can you show an image of the result

Comment: Uploaded to bottom. Upvoting you up for now as it's already better!